# How to check whether sample rate really work in GA Dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a bit issue after set up sample rate on site as below,

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto', {'sampleRate': 6});
```

we don't see the message at the top of the report that says "This report is based on N% of sessions" at all. Could you advise? or there's any another way to check in GA Dashboard?

Answer (score -1):

You have set the sample rate at 6%. Hence sending traffic activity of only six percent of your site users(not sessions) to Google Analytics. 
A similar question posted in the past: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398373/what-is-the-relationship-between-samplerate-and-various-google-analytics-reports

Are you seeing any drop in traffic since switching the sample rate to 6%?

Comment: it show no active user on site at all, but it might due to staging environment which have only a few users who is view site?
Regarding your explanation, our set-up is sample user not session, so it show no message  "This report is based on N% of sessions", is that correct?

Comment: how much traffic does your website get? The message that you are referring to appears when the total traffic for the applied time frame crosses 250,000 sessions.